# why is my form not submiting using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

bit of a selfish question but I am really strugerling with ajax in general so I need some help. So basically Im trying to update and sql database using an 'onblur' function. heres my code:

code on index.php

```
   function saveStatus(){
var status =document.getElementById("statusForm").value;
$.ajax({
                url: 'saveStatus.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'feed_id=' + status,
                success: function(result){
                }
              }    
    <form id="statusUpdate" action = "whosout.php" method="post"> 
        <input type="text" id="statusForm" onblur="saveStatus()" 
        placeholder="<?php if($status!=null){ echo '&lsquo;'.$status.'&rsquo;';}
        else { echo 'Enter your status here.';}?>"> 
        </form>
```

and code on saveStatus.php

```
    <?
     require 'core.php';
     require 'connect.php';

      $status = $_POST['feed_id'];
      $idPerson = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $query = "UPDATE person SET status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."' 
     WHERE idPerson = '$idPerson'"; 
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
     ?>
```

at the moment the sql database does not update when i click of the input box. Any help would be great!!

Comment: Please attempt to narrow down error.

Comment: Check for errors in your browser's console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer:**

1. You have to devide scripts and html output
2. You forget `);`.You have to close `$.ajax` block.
3. You miss `}` closing function `saveStatus()`.

Code:

```
<script>
function saveStatus(){
    var status =document.getElementById("statusForm").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveStatus.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'feed_id=' + status,
        success: function(result){

        }
    }); // <-- Also, you forget `);` here 
} // <-- Also, you foget closing `}` here
</script>

<form id="statusUpdate" action = "whosout.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" id="statusForm" onblur="saveStatus()" 
placeholder="<?php if($status!=null){ echo '&lsquo;'.$status.'&rsquo;';}
else { echo 'Enter your status here.';}?>"> 
</form>
```

**Not error, but advice:**

Also, note this: you used jQuery `ajax` function, so use jQuery in other cases too (you used pure JavaScript instead).

You getting value this way:

```
var status = document.getElementById("statusForm").value;
```

Use jQuery syntax instead:

```
var status = $("#statusForm").val();
```

**Additional info**

As, @Utkanos noticed in comments to this answer:

> ...all of which would be obvious if you look in the error console.

You have to use some debug tool, like FireBug or DevTools (Chrome, also in Chrome you can use CTRL+SHIFT+J). Not have to. You MUST do it.

Comment: ...all of which would be obvious if you look in the error console.

Comment: Also, mention about `$('#statusForm').val()` instead of `var status =document.getElementById("statusForm").value;`.